# function関数を用いたプログラミングに苦戦

Tags: python, random, julia

将来的に並列計算を行うために、以前質問させていただいたコード中のfor文3つを３つの関数に分けてもう少しきれいなコードにしたく、取り組んでいますが、以前質問したような欲しい結果がうまくでません。おそらくは初期値を代入するときに変なことをしている。。？
pythonでもそうだったのですが,簡単なdef関数やfunction関数は理解しているのですが、自分で複雑な関数を作ろうとするといつもつまずいてしまい、結局一つの文に収めてしまう傾向にあります。
並列計算をするためにもここで克服したいと思っています。
以下にコードをあげます。
元のコードです。

```
function main()
        n = 3
        count0=0
        count1=0
        count2=0
        count3=0
        count4=0
        count5=0
        count6=0
        count7=0
        stage = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
        stage[:,:,1]=[1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1]
        stage[:,:,2]=[1 0 1;0 0 0;1 0 1]
        stage[:,:,3]=[1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1]
        #println(walk)
        for itr in 1:10
            walk = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
            walk[1,1,1]=1
            for t in 0:6
                next_walk = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
                number=rand(UnitRange{Int8}(1:6))
                if t==0
                    count0 += 1
                else
                    for x = 1:n, y = 1:n, z =1:n
                        x1 = ((x-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                        x2 = ((x+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                        y1 = ((y-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                        y2 = ((y+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                        z1 = ((z-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1 
                        z2 = ((z+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                        if stage[x,y,z]== 0
                            continue
                        else
                            if walk[x,y,z]== 0
                                continue
                            else
                                if number == 1
                                    if stage[x2,y,z]==1
                                        next_walk[x2,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    else
                                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    end
                                elseif number == 2
                                    if stage[x,y2,z]==1
                                        next_walk[x,y2,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    else
                                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    end
                                elseif number == 3
                                    if stage[x,y,z2]==1
                                        next_walk[x,y,z2]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    else
                                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    end
                                elseif number == 4
                                    if stage[x1,y,z]==1
                                        next_walk[x1,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    else
                                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    end
                                elseif number == 5
                                    if stage[x,y1,z]==1
                                        next_walk[x,y1,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    else
                                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    end
                                elseif number == 6
                                    if stage[x,y,z1]==1
                                        next_walk[x,y,z1]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    else
                                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                    end
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                　　walk = copy(next_walk)
                #println(t,walk,"\n")
                if t == 6
                    if walk[1,1,1]==1
                        count1 += 1
                    else
                        continue
                    end
                elseif t == 36
                    if walk[1,1,1]==1
                        count2 += 1
                    else
                        continue
                    end
                elseif t == 216
                    if walk[1,1,1]==1
                        count3 += 1
                    else
                        continue
                    end
                else
                    continue
                        #1296,7776,46656
                end
                end
            end
        #println("t=0:",count0,"\n","t=6:",count1,"\n","t=36:",count2,"\n","t=216:",count3,"\n","t=1296:",count4,"\n","t=7776:",count5,"\n","t=46656:",count6,"\n")
        end
        println("t=0:",count0,"\n","t=6:",count1,"\n","t=36:",count2,"\n","t=216:",count3,"\n","t=1296:",count4,"\n","t=7776:",count5,"\n","t=46656:",count6,"\n")
    end
    main()
```

改良中のコードです（上を参考にしています）。

```
 n=3
    stage1 = zeros(Int8,3,3,3)
    stage1[:,:,1]=[1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1]
    stage1[:,:,2]=[1 0 1;0 0 0;1 0 1]
    stage1[:,:,3]=[1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1]
    Stage = copy(stage1)
function random(stage,number,walk,next_walk)#すべての座標でランダムウォーク
    for x = 1:n, y = 1:n, z =1:n
        x1 = ((x-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
        x2 = ((x+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
        y1 = ((y-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
        y2 = ((y+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
        z1 = ((z-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1 
        z2 = ((z+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
        if stage[x,y,z]== 0
            continue
        else
            if walk[x,y,z]== 0
                continue
            else
                if number == 1
                    if stage[x2,y,z]==1
                        next_walk[x2,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                    else
                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                    end
                elseif number == 2
                    if stage[x,y2,z]==1
                        next_walk[x,y2,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                    else
                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                    end
                elseif number == 3
                    if stage[x,y,z2]==1
                        next_walk[x,y,z2]=walk[x,y,z]
                    else
                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                    end
                elseif number == 4
                    if stage[x1,y,z]==1
                        next_walk[x1,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                    else
                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                    end
                elseif number == 5
                    if stage[x,y1,z]==1
                        next_walk[x,y1,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                    else
                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                    end
                elseif number == 6
                    if stage[x,y,z1]==1
                        next_walk[x,y,z1]=walk[x,y,z]
                    else
                        next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    walk = copy(next_walk)
    return walk
end

function step_walk(time) #上の関数をt秒間繰り返し、t=xのときの原点にいたら１をたしていき、ｔ秒後の各countを返したい
    walk = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
    walk[1,1,1]=1
    direction=rand(UnitRange{Int8}(1:6))
    count0 = 0
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    for t in 0:time
        if t== 0
            count0 += 1
        else
            next_walk=zeros(Int8,n,n,n)#毎秒初期化
            walker = random(Stage,direction,walk,next_walk)
            if t==2 && walker[1,1,1]==1
                count1 += 1
            elseif t==4 && walker[1,1,1]==1
                count2 += 1
            else
                continue
            end
        end
    end
    return count0,count1,count2
end
#show(step_walk(10))#この時点でおかしい

function experiment(time,itr) #上のｔ秒後のランダムウォークの結果をitr回繰り返し、最終的な各countを返したい。
    for i in 0:itr
        walk = zeros(Int,n,n,n)#itr毎に初期化
        step_walk(time)
    end
    return step_walk(time)
end 
experiment(10,10)
```

結果

```
(1,0,0)#少なくとも(10,?,?)とでるはず。
```

今、現在進行形で勉強中ですが、defやfunction関数が分かっているようでわかっていないこのもどかしさをどうにかしたい、、、、。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 質問の意図としては三重ループをどうしたいのでしょうか。質問のタイトルも苦戦しているという日記ではなく、概要を書いてください。

Comment: 関数に分割したいと書いてあるのですが、その意味がわからないということですか？

Comment: 意味が分からないというか意味があるのか分かりませんでした。for文の中身を関数に分割すると"きれいになる"、という前提が間違いでなければ、回答はつくかもしれません。

Comment: 今、並列化を勉強しており、自分の質問がナンセンスであることがわかりました。。本質はそこではなかったみたいです。この質問は消そうと思います。